# Updating one value in angular model according to another input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have a model in angular, with three variables in my model, say `a,b,c`, and I want to have `c=a*b`.

I've done it by adding a function, `updateC()`, that updates `c`, and then my HTML would look like this:

```
<input name="a" ng-model="a" ng-change="updateC()"></input>
<input name="b" ng-model="b" ng-change="updateC()"></input>
<input name="c" ng-model="c" readonly></input>
```

But that's not a nice solution if I have alot of such triplets, because I need to define a function for each such triplet. Is there a way to bind the value of the element in the model to some formula?
I.e. is there some attribute `ng-like-bind-but-updates-model` such that the following html will work:

```
<input name="a" ng-model="a"></input>
<input name="b" ng-model="b"></input>
<input name="c" ng-model="c" ng-like-bind-but-updates-model="a*b" readonly></input>
```

Comment: Have you tried `value` and the `{{...}}` binding instead of `ng-model`? I.e. `<input name="c" value="{{ a*b }}" readonly />`.

Comment: you can just use `<input name="c" ng-model="a * b" readonly></input>`

Comment: Both won't work: https://jsfiddle.net/1j5grwhy/
@yarons the idea is to have a model that has a variable named `c` with the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice trick that solves your problem:

```
<input name="c" ng-model="c = a * b" readonly />
```

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Ylkp7sitmSKp76mHzeq?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, not sure if that's what you want to achieve:

```
<input name="a" ng-model="a"></input>
<input name="b" ng-model="b"></input>
<input name="c" value="{{c=a*b}}" readonly></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply bind the value of input C

```
<input name="c" value="{{c=a*b}}"></input>
<label>{{c}}</label>
```

like this:
http://codepen.io/Visualife/pen/xwNKjj

you'll need to handle initial values though for a & b.

Comment: You mean with `ng-bind`?

Comment: no, with value, please see the codepen I've attached mate

Comment: Sorry, commented before You've added the codepen.
I want to have a variable named `c` in my scope, and your solution is essentially the same as using `ng-bind`, it won't update `c` inside the scope itself.

Comment: then you can set c inside 'value' as per the update and updated pen